# How can I iterate over an XML file and display the data in a HTML web page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I want to iterate over an XML file and display the data from the fields on a HTML webpage. At the moment, my code only displays the first entry in the XML file.

**Here is my current HTML/JS code, which displays the first entry in my XML file. This is a html file:**

```html
<script>
displayCD(0);

function displayCD(i) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this, i);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml, i) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contact");
    document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML =
    "Name: " +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Email: " +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Phone: " + 
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("phone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}


</script>
<div id='showCD'></div><br>
```

**Here is my XML code, in a separate file, data.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entries>
  <contact>
    <name>a</name>
    <email>b</email>
    <phone>1234</phone>
  </contact>
  <contact>
    <name>c</name>
    <email>d</email>
    <phone>5678</phone>
  </contact>
</entries>
```

**Current output:**

Name: a

Email: b

Phone: 1234

**Expected output:**

Name: a

Email: b

Phone: 1234

Name: c

Email: d

Phone: 5678

Comment: If you're just *translating* XML to HTML, why not use XSLT?

Comment: @CD001, IMHO XSLT can be quite difficult for some people to learn, it has a very different paradigm to most languages and it's not always easy to understand why something is happening (to start off with).

Comment: @NigelRen ... maybe, but this is pretty much *exactly* what it's for - and if you're used to XML anyway \*shrugs\* ... funny thing - my mum spent decades working with databases and C, probably forgot more than I know, and she could never get comfortable with XML at all.

Comment: If you're working with XML, then you really should take the trouble to learn XSLT. There's an initial learning curve, but once you're over it, it's vastly more concise and maintainable than low-level Javscript DOM navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop over `x` (which represents all the `<contact>` tags:

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contact");

for (count = 0; count < x.length; count++) {
  document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML +=
    "Name: " +
    x[count].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Email: " +
    x[count].getElementsByTagName("email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Phone: " + 
    x[count].getElementsByTagName("phone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

P.S. As someone mentioned in the comments, using XSLT would probably be a neater way of doing this overall, although there is a bit of a learning curve if you haven't used it before.

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly. XSLT would most likely be above my level at the moment, considering my current project is my first time doing XML and Javascript.